# Trie based keyword searching vs Binary search

Tags: binary, trie

I implemented a trie based search and compared it with binary search. According to me trie based search should be more optimum than binary search when we have huge text files but when i used java's clock function to check the time, results were other way round. Can someone explain me?

Comment: What do you mean with binary search. Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

With binary string search you need to have sorted list. IMO sorting and searching is more expensive then a trie.